# Google 0Auth authentication is not giving any response

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

// authrouter

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import {User, IUser} from '../Models/User';
const passport =  require("passport")


const authRouter : express.Router = express.Router();


// login route
authRouter.get("/google",passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['email', 'profile']}))
authRouter.get("/login/failure",(req:Request,res:Response)=>{
    res.status(401).json({
        success : false,
        message:"Login Failed"
    })
})

authRouter.get('/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000',
    failureRedirect: "/login/failure"
  })
);
authRouter.get("/login/success",(req:Request,res:Response)=>{
    console.log(req.user)
    if(req.user){
        res.status(200).json({
            success : true,
            message:"Logged in Successfully",
            user : req.user
        })
    }
    res.send("you are logged in")
})

export default authRouter;
```

I'm trying to implement google 0auth using passportjs , but after I'm clicking on the account although I'm getting redirected to the successRedirect url but not getting the json response.

when I'm using auth/login/success to get the response it is not giving any response.

Comment: Your successRedirect is not going to `/login/success` and this endpoint would not get a JSON body, it would get request parameters

Comment: how to write the route so that after successful login if someone send get request to auth/login/success  then get the response?